Do ER diagrams help directly answer "any" relationship question?
Situation
In the image below

one can answer relationship questions between team-team, team-play, play-referee very simply.
But trying to figure out the relation between team-referee is not trivial, since there are two possible paths on the team side.
To answer it, I created the tables, and it obviously turned out team-referee have a man-many relation.
Question
ER diagrams are supposed to be "complete" and represent your database at a high level, and the diagram above does satisfy this definition.
But

I want to confirm if its true ER diagrams don't neccesarily make it "trivial" to answer relations between any two entities?
Would adding a direct link between referee and team, just for ease (that it is a many-many relation) be wrong, or unncessary?
Is there a spec for ER diagramming, or is it loosely defined?

Read 'Database System Concepts' by Abraham Silberschatz
Looked on the web for a ER diagram spec
Checked question on stack overflow

I personally don't usually find these kinds of diagrams easy to interpret.
A simple textual description like the below, took me less than 60 seconds to type and lay out even on a mobile phone, and for anyone who both understands databases and has a rudimentary knowledge of football, it is probably clearer and more suggestive than the diagram about what the schema really looks like and the relationships between tables (as implied by the column names alone, without providing any other information about constraints).
Teams
  TeamName

Referees
  RefereeName

Matches
  MatchDate
  HomeTeamName
  AwayTeamName
  RefereeName

I think as well that a conceptual description of how football is played would be best provided separately from, and prior to, a description of how basic clerical records about football matches might be structured.
ER diagrams are not a general-purpose description of the world or a particularly useful teaching device. Most of us probably made it through school without ever having any area of knowledge explained to us through the prism of an ER diagram.
If I wanted to know what the relationship is between referees and teams, I would certainly first turn to my understanding of football itself, as distinct from anything I understand about record-keeping and database modelling.
Once already armed with knowledge about what concepts exist in football and how the game works, it becomes much easier to look at structured records and infer the likely relationships and workings of the record-keeping system.
In this respect, I think ER diagrams often attempt to do too much. They attempt to replace real teaching and background knowledge - which might take considerable amounts of natural language description, a variety of diagrams (taking no particular standard form), and probably an element of real witnessing of football matches being played - with some toy-town (or even downright imaginary) diagram of the concepts.
At the same time, ER diagrams are abstract from the programming languages and written/visual forms programmers actually use to describe database schemas or view structured data.
